# Can I access and get Magento data through / into an Android App?

Tags: android, magento

I am developing an **Android App for an E-Commerce** company and i ***need to access the online Magento database*** for their catalog through an Android app. So please ***guide me a way for the solution*** and also **provide suitable tutorials** if you find any because i did not get any tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create webservice. using webservice you can get it data from server

like this you can parse the data from the server

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I know how to parse json into Android, but not getting how to implement webservice to encode Magento data into JSON

Comment: @Sun did you find the solution?